# Save values from a DHT11-Sensor to influxDB container

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, gpio, dht

I'm trying to save the values that I'm reading from my DHT11 sensor, which is connected to my Raspberry Pi GPIO, to an InfluxDB container. I want to utilize Node-Red plugins to establish a connection between the sensor and the database. I'm curious about the specific service or interface needed to accomplish this, and which approach would be the simplest and most relevant?

Is it possible to write a Python script to directly send the values to an InfluxDB container using its IP address?

Comment: First of all, add your code that you think is buggy. Second, enable driver in the Linux kernel and device tree and use it.